# Trying to make this alter table constraint using wildcard characters

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create an alter table constraint that follows this description:

Customer Table:
Add a 30 character optional attribute called Email which must follow a valid email format as follows.
At least 3 characters before and after the @ sign
At least 2 characters after the dot/period

The code I've tried seems to work with a regular e-mail format.

```
Alter Table Customer
    Add Email char (30) null
    Constraint CK_Customer_Email_EmailFormat
        Check (Email Like '_%_%_%@_%_%_%_._%_%')
```

Comment: Other than the excessive percent signs and the extra character after the @ sign, it seems OK. You didn't say what the problem was.

Comment: I just couldn't figure out how to actually implement the wildcards correctly and just winged it. I tried inserting bad data to test it and I got errors but couldn't interpret it if the constraint was working as intended. (I am brand new to SQL).

Comment: Ok, well it seems fine to me. The actual wildcards can be written like this:         Check (Email Like '___%@___%.__%')   This means at least 3 chars followed by anything else, then the @ sign, then another 3 chars, etc.

Comment: Ohhh okay I get it now, thank you so much for your help! You're a lifesaver!